# Downloading embedded video

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, download

For the 1st time I had switched to using gnu/linux. I'm using linux-mint 20.

I have a problem with downloading online videos from the websites now because idm is not available for linux. When I was using windows, I needed to just log in to this website,there you go, baam, video download link appeared from idm.

Since I am using linux now, I had installed XDM but it didn't automatically capture the video from this website.

Is there any software that works just like idm ??? What can I do to download this video??

Comment: Use the search engine of your choice and look for `youtube-dl`

Comment: Thanx. Will look for

Comment: Depending on the Web browser you use, there are plugins to do that (e.g., Video DownloadHelper in Firefox)

Answer (score 0):

You need a browser add-on to capture the video from a webpage. e,g :[Video Downloader professional](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloader-profession/). IDM has also a browser add-on to capture video.